# How do we define 'true p2p'

Tags: network-programming, p2p, jxta, adobe-stratus

I have seen a number of questions in which the term 'true p2p' is used. What exactly is meant by this term, if it has an exact meaning? I am familiar with the term p2p, and I can think of several possible meanings for 'true p2p'. What does it mean to you?

What are some examples of:

a) 'true' p2p?

b) 'untrue p2p'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that by "true P2P" you mean "pure P2P".

Pure P2P means totally decentralization. I.e. true P2P doesnt have a central coordinator server.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would differ slightly from Tom - I think a piece of software can be regarded as peer-to-peer if peer communication is a substantial part of the way it works. So Skype and Napster are/were P2P even though they require co-ordinating servers.

I've not come across the term 'true P2P' - it may be referring to the fact that some people use it as a marketing buzzword without knowing what it means.